# Cannot contribute extension from a fragment

Tags: eclipse-plugin, fragment, eclipse-kepler

I am working on a set of plugins and fragments on eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) but using the 3.x model.

One plugin contains part of the application model and has a fragment which contributes some model editors. (This seems right to me - tell me if it's unnecessarily complicated)

In the main app these editor contributions are not listed. I changed the fragment to a plugin and the editors became visible.

I could change the fragment to a plugin but this would mean that I have to expose more of the model.

I could move the fragment to the host plugin but this would mean mixing model and view (perhaps not a big deal)

Is it generally not possible to contribute from a fragment or have I done something wrong?

Here is the fragment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<fragment>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="com.acme.atf.device.ui.editors.NullConfigEditor"
            default="false"
            id="827299e9-6039-4a76-bfa6-08ef2d7f8724"
            name="VariableEditor">
      </editor>
      <editor
            class="com.acme.atf.device.ui.editors.SerialConfigEditor"
            default="false"
            id="cbaba4b2-8380-4ae5-9896-542cf97ca8cc"
            name="SerialEditor">
      </editor>
   </extension>
```

**Further information**

The plugin hierarchy looks like this: (P=plugin, F=fragment)

```
com.acme.atf.app (P)
com.acme.atf.device (P)
com.acme.atf.device.help (F)
com.acme.atf.device.ui (F)
com.acme.atf.model (P)
com.acme.atf.core.ui (P)
```

An action in `com.acme.atf.app` attempts to load an editor (which happens to be in `device.ui`) which cannot be found. If I change `device.ui`to a plugin then the editor is found.

Comment: There is no problem contributing extensions in a fragment. I just tested contributing an editor similar to your example and it worked fine.

Comment: @greg-449 - thanks! Did you try that as a 3.x compatible RCP app? Wonder why it doesn't work for me...

Comment: It has to be 3.x as e4 does not have editors! I tested with plug-ins in a full Eclipse RCP as I don't have a suitable RCP to test. What do you mean by 'does not show up'?

Comment: @greg-449 - I try to open an editor by id - not found. I listed all contributed editors and those in the fragment were not listed. `Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.ui.editors").getExtensions()`

Comment: Does the fragment have a `Fragment-Host` in the `manifest.mf`? Is  the parent plugin of the fragment declared to be a singleton?

Comment: @greg-449 - yes to both questions

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to solve very similar problem with Eclipse 4.4.1. Unfortunately, the solution was to use clean workspace (I've imported my projects from Git).
Before that, I tried "playing" with version numbers of host and fragment, singleton flags, recreating fragment project, cleaning all projects and configuration of my RCP app. Also, I used OSGI console trying to get some additional info, but it reported only that:

- Host plug-in org.aaa.bbb is in ACTIVE state (with no fragments)
- Fragment bundle is in INSTALLED state (reporting "Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.aaa.bbb")

I think this is a bug and garbaged workspace (launch) configuration may be the cause. Hope this helps someone.